# Problem trying to mock more than one Java Interface

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I've been writting some tests for a legacy web app on java using DeltaSpike, Weld, Hibernate and others frameworks.
I have faced some problem with my first test class that injects many Mocked interfaces on a Service.

Let me show some code:
Service to be tested

```
public class DistribuicaoProcessoManualServiceImpl extends DistribuicaoService implements DistribuicaoProcessoManualService {
    
@Inject
@WebServiceTJDBEntityManager EntityManager wstjEM;  


private ForoTJComarcaMPRepository foroMPRepository;
private AssuntoTJNaturezaMPRepository naturezaMPRepository;
private VaraTJVaraMPRepository varaMPRepository;
private ClasseTJTipoMPRepository tipoMPRepository;
private ProcessoRepository processoRepository;
private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;
private UsuarioDaSessao usuarioDaSessao;

/**
 * @deprecated CDI eyes only
 */
public DistribuicaoProcessoManualServiceImpl() {
    this(null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}

@Inject
public DistribuicaoProcessoManualServiceImpl(
        ForoTJComarcaMPRepository foroMPRepository,
        AssuntoTJNaturezaMPRepository naturezaMPRepository,
        ClasseTJTipoMPRepository tipoMPRepository,
        ProcessoRepository processoRepository,
        UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository,
        UsuarioDaSessao usuarioDaSessao,
        VaraTJVaraMPRepository varaMPRepository) {
    this.foroMPRepository = foroMPRepository;
    this.naturezaMPRepository = naturezaMPRepository;
    this.tipoMPRepository = tipoMPRepository;
    this.processoRepository = processoRepository;
    this.usuarioRepository = usuarioRepository;
    this.usuarioDaSessao = usuarioDaSessao;
    this.varaMPRepository = varaMPRepository;
}
    
        @Override
        @Transactional(readOnly = false, qualifier = {WebServiceTJDBEntityManager.class})
        public Processo vinculaOuPreparaParaEspecializacao(Processo processo) {
            
            //Service do some validations here with Guava's Preconditions;
            
            Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository.procurarPorLogin(usuarioDaSessao.getUsuario().getLogin());
            processo.atualizaInformacoesDeProcuradoriaEUsuario(usuario);
            
            ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP processoDePara = compoeMapeamento(processo);
            
            VaraTJVaraMP varaMP = varaMPRepository.procurarPorIdVaraTJForoEPorProcuradoria(processoDePara);
            
            ForoTJComarcaMP comarcaMP = foroMPRepository.procurarPorIdForoEPorProcuradoria(processoDePara);
            AssuntoTJNaturezaMP naturezaMP = naturezaMPRepository.procurarPorAssuntoEPorProcuradoria(processoDePara);
            ClasseTJTipoMP tipoMP = tipoMPRepository.procurarPorCodigoEPorProcuradoria(processoDePara);
            
            processoDePara
                .comComarcaMP(comarcaMP)
                .comVaraMP(varaMP)
                .comNaturezaMP(naturezaMP)
                .comTipoMP(tipoMP);
            
            processoRepository.inclui(processo);    
                
            return processo;
        }
    }
```

The extended Class:

```
public abstract class DistribuicaoService {
    
    public ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP compoeMapeamento(Processo processo) {
        return new ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP(processo);
    }

}
```

The mapper/builder/aggregator:

```
public class ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private final Processo processo;

    public ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP(final Processo processo) {
        this.processo = processo;
        this.comCamaraMP( OrgaoJulgadorTJCamaraMP.semEfeito() )
                .comRelatorMP( RelatorTJRelatorMP.semEfeito() )
                .comOrigemMP( new OrgaoJulgadorTJOrigemMP() )
                .comTipoDeRemessaMP();
    }

    
    public ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP comComarcaMP(ComarcaMP comarcaMP) {
        processo.getDadosOrigem().setCodigoComarcaMP(comarcaMP.getIdComarca());
        return this;
    }

    public ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP comVaraMP(VaraMP varaMP) {
        processo.getDadosOrigem().setCodigoVaraMP(varaMP.getIdVaraMP());
        return this;
    }
    
    public ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP comNaturezaMP(AssuntoTJNaturezaMP naturezaMP) {
        processo.getAssuntoPrincipal().setCodigoNaturezaMP(naturezaMP.getIdNatureza());
        return this;
    }

    public ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP comTipoMP(ClasseTJTipoMP tipoMP) {
        processo.getDadosProcesso().getClasse().setCodigoTipoMP(tipoMP.getIdTipo());
        return this;
    }
    
    ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP comCamaraMP(OrgaoJulgadorTJCamaraMP camaraMP) {
        processo.getDadosDistribuicao().getMapeamento().setCodigoCamaraMP(camaraMP.getIdCamara());
        return this;
    }
    
    ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP comRelatorMP(RelatorTJRelatorMP relatorMP) {
        processo.getDadosDistribuicao().getMapeamento().setCodigoRelatorMP(relatorMP.getIdRelatorMP());
        return this;
    }
    
    ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP comOrigemMP(OrgaoJulgadorTJOrigemMP origemMP) {
        processo.getDadosDistribuicao().getMapeamento().setCodigoOrigemMP(origemMP.getIdOrigem());
        return this;
    }

    ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP comTipoDeRemessaMP() {
        processo.setTipoRemessa(TipoDeRemessa.fromTipoDeProcesso(this.processo.getProcessoVirtualTJ()));
        return this;
    }

    public Procuradoria getProcuradoria() {
        return processo.getProcuradoria();
    }

    public Integer getCodigoForoTJ() {
        return processo.getDadosOrigem().getCodigoForoPrimeiraInstancia();
    }

    public Integer getCodigoVaraTJ() {
        return processo.getDadosOrigem().getCodigoVaraPrimeiraInstancia();
    }

    public List<Parte> getPartes() {
        return processo.getPartes();
    }

    public String getNomeAssuntoTJ() {
        return processo.getAssuntoPrincipal().getDescricaoAssunto();
    }

    public Integer getCodigoClasseTJ() {
        return processo.getDadosProcesso().getClasse().getCodigoClasse();
    }
    
    public String getNomeOrgaoJulgadorTJ() {
        return processo.getDadosDistribuicao().getOrgaoJulgador().getNomeOrgaoJulgador();
    }
    
    public String getNomeRelatorTJ() {
        return processo.getDadosDistribuicao().getRelator().getNomeRelator();
    }
    
    public Integer getIdAssuntoTJ() {
        return processo.getAssuntoPrincipal().getCodigoAssunto();
    }


    public Movimentacao getUltimoMovimento() {
        return null;
    }
```

Class for Test:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DistribuicaoProcessoManualServiceTest {
    
    
    @Mock private ForoTJComarcaMPRepository foroMPRepository;
    @Mock private AssuntoTJNaturezaMPRepository naturezaMPRepository;
    @Mock private VaraTJVaraMPRepository varaMPRepository;
    @Mock private ClasseTJTipoMPRepository tipoMPRepository;
    @Mock private ProcessoRepository processoRepository;
    @Mock private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;
    
    @Mock private Usuario usuario;
    @Mock private Procuradoria procuradoria;
    @Mock private VaraTJVaraMP varaMP;
    @Mock private ForoTJComarcaMP comarcaMP;
    @Mock private AssuntoTJNaturezaMP naturezaMP;
    @Mock private ClasseTJTipoMP tipoMP;
    @Mock private UsuarioDaSessao usuarioDaSessao;
    
    @InjectMocks    
    private DistribuicaoProcessoManualServiceImpl service = new DistribuicaoProcessoManualServiceImpl();
    
    
    private Processo processo;
    
    
    @Before
    public void setUpMethod() {
        initMocks(this);
        
        //Others Builders for populate "processo" here;
        
        processo = ProcessoBuilder()
                        .com(hoje)
                        .com(PARECER)
                        .com(FISICO)
                        .com(dadosProcesso)
                        .com(dadosOrigem)
                        .com(distribuicao)
                        .com(fila)
                        .cria();        
        
        ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP mapeamento = new ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP(processo);
        
        when(usuario.getLogin()).thenReturn("luizrodriguesj");
        when(usuario.getProcuradoria()).thenReturn(procuradoria);
        when(usuarioDaSessao.getUsuario()).thenReturn(usuario);
        when(usuarioRepository.procurarPorLogin(anyString())).thenReturn(usuario);
        
        when(comarcaMP.getIdComarca()).thenReturn(1);
        when(foroMPRepository.procurarPorIdForoEPorProcuradoria(mapeamento)).thenReturn(comarcaMP);
        
        when(varaMP.getIdVaraMP()).thenReturn(1);
        when(varaMPRepository.procurarPorIdVaraTJForoEPorProcuradoria(mapeamento)).thenReturn(varaMP);
        
        when(naturezaMP.getIdNatureza()).thenReturn(1);
        when(naturezaMPRepository.procurarPorAssuntoEPorProcuradoria(mapeamento)).thenReturn(naturezaMP);
        
        when(tipoMP.getIdTipo()).thenReturn(1);
        when(tipoMPRepository.procurarPorCodigoEPorProcuradoria(mapeamento)).thenReturn(tipoMP);        
        
    }
```

Method with problem:

```
@Test(expected = ApplicationException.class)
public void naoPermitirDistribuicaoDeProcessoSemUmMapeamentoDeVaraCorrespondente() {
    service.vinculaOuPreparaParaEspecializacao(processo);
}
```

The interface that it was possible to mock:

```
public interface UsuarioRepository extends GenericDAO<Usuario, Long> {
    
    boolean isAutenticavel(Usuario usuario);
    Usuario procurarPorLogin(String login);
    List<Usuario> lista(UsuarioPesquisa pesquisa, Paginacao paginacao);
}
```

One of Interfaces that not obey instruction mock and return null:

```
public interface ForoTJComarcaMPRepository extends GenericDAO<ForoTJComarcaMP, Long> {

    ForoTJComarcaMP procurarPorIdForoEPorProcuradoria(ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP processoDePara);
    List<ForoTJComarcaMP> lista(DominioMPPesquisa pesquisa, Paginacao paginacao);
    ForoTJComarcaMP procuraPorForoTJ(ForoTJComarcaMP foroTJComarcaMP);
    ForoTJComarcaMP procuraPorEntidade(ForoTJComarcaMP clone);
    List<ForoTJComarcaMP> listaMapeamentoDistinctPor(Procuradoria procuradoria);
}
```

After others methods in this class that runs without any problem, this last one just fails because a NullPointerException (NPE) that occurs in:

```
VaraTJVaraMP varaMP = varaMPRepository.procurarPorIdVaraTJForoEPorProcuradoria(processoDePara);
AssuntoTJNaturezaMP naturezaMP = naturezaMPRepository.procurarPorAssuntoEPorProcuradoria(processoDePara);
ClasseTJTipoMP tipoMP = tipoMPRepository.procurarPorCodigoEPorProcuradoria(processoDePara);
ForoTJComarcaMP comarcaMP = foroMPRepository.procurarPorIdForoEPorProcuradoria(processoDePara);

....

// The references "comarcaMP", "varaMP", "naturezaMP", "tipoMP" are null here and next step throws a NPE.

processoDePara
            .comComarcaMP(comarcaMP)
```

Other Mocked Interface declared work without problem, like this one:

```
Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository.procurarPorLogin(usuarioDaSessao.getUsuario().getLogin());
```

Where the "usuario" reference is setted as declared on setup method in Test Class.

Sorry for any mistake or lack of more informations.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Your code is not complete. It is not showing how mapeamento on functional code is created, which to be done by compoeMapeamento.
However, following this line of dependencies is going to be hard, you can use debug mode to see what is happening, probably ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP class does not have an equal method.
I see a bigger issue here. You code is doing to much in a single function, in order to test it you need to mock a lot of things, in the end your unit test is not really unit and you are working a lot more by writing it and making it work.

Comment: Tks for help! Unfortunately, you are right. Classes are giants and can be splitted in small pieces like private methods. Besides of that, "vinculaOuPreparaParaEspecializacao" method runs bellow a transaction, it was 2 and I have spplited it. The clas ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP, has no Eq & Hsc but it wont be persisted or compared with another in runtime. This object is like a mapper/builder from root bean "Processo" who aggregates others information. Is it required for mock objects or something in runtime? I am going to edit original post to make more sense... Thanks a lot man...

Comment: Mockito calls to equals and hashcode to determine if arguments provided to mock calls are the desired ones. Since ProcessoDoTJMapeamentoParaMP, mockito won't consider it was called unless it is the same specific instance.
You code example is to big, at least for me to be able to point exactly the reason it fails. However, my suggestion is you to use debugger in any IDE.

Comment: Again, thx in advanced. I was debbuging before posting this question and just not recognize the the solution, only the mocks and null objects. The class has so many lines in which methods, because its a legacy system and I have been refactoring it splitting in small pieces of code. I have assume this risk because its so hard to change things or give maintenance.